# Openlayers 3 : massive lag when adding tmsoverlay with ol.layer.Tile

Tags: openlayers-3

I am using Openlayers 3.11.2 to display some tile from MapTiler with the following codes (I don't have time to make a subset version from my existing code) :

`var tmsoverlay = new ol.layer.Tile({
    extent: [11709337.567029998, 2240165.3239744995,
             11710560.559481502, 2241388.3164259996],

    source: new ol.source.TileImage({
        tileGrid: new ol.tilegrid.TileGrid({
          extent: [11709337.567029998, 2240165.3239744995,
                   11710560.559481502, 2241388.3164259996],
          minZoom: 17,
          resolutions: [1.19432856674194,
                        0.59716428337097,
                        0.29858214168549,
                        0.14929107084274,
                        0.07464553542137
                       ],
        }),
        tileUrlFunction: function(coordinate) {
                if (coordinate === null) return undefined;
                // TMS Style URL
                var z = coordinate[0];
                var x = coordinate[1];
                var y = coordinate[2];
                var url = z + "/" + x + "/" + y + "." + this.type;
                return url;
            }
    })
});
map.addLayer(tmsoverlay);`

while I try to pan toward the custom tile, It start lagging and then crash the browser. and there are nothing written to console. Any helps?